# JSON data response

Tags: geojson, point, json, api, ogc-api

I need to obtain point features for UNESCO sites of italy in JSON format using :-UNESCO POIs (OGC API): https://demo.pygeoapi.io/master/collections/unesco_pois_italy. But unfortunately I am not able to get it. It look like this OGC API don't contain point features in JSON format. What's the matter here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OGC API request to use for reading the features from this service is https://demo.pygeoapi.io/master/collections/unesco_pois_italy/items?f=json.

However, when I tried it the response is a generic error message

```
{
    "code": "NoApplicableCode",
    "description": "generic error (check logs)"
}
```

The description of the service is

> Unesco Points of Interest in Italy. Using GeoSolutions GeoServer WFS
> demo-server as backend WFS.

It looks like the demo is down now.

Comment: Yeah, it seems it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

The FQDN of the backend WFS server from GeoSolutions changed to https://gs-stable.geosolutionsgroup.com/geoserver/wfs?request=GetCapabilities.

PR to fix the issue has been submitted and merged https://github.com/geopython/demo.pygeoapi.io/pull/37